# Cannot set refresh rate in hybrid graphics setup (NVIDIA and INTEL)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, display-resolution, hybrid

I've bought a new laptop with Windows but decided to give Ubuntu a try.

The Specs of The Laptop:

- Intel® Core™ i7-10875H CPU
- 16GB Ram
- Nvidia RTX 3060 Laptop GPU

Using:

- Ubuntu 21.04 (Fully up-to-date)
- 5.11.0-37-generic Kernel

For battery life purposes, I've been using the laptop in Hybrid Graphics mode (as stated by MSHYBRID in the laptop's BIOS)

The problem is, in Ubuntu (or in any other Linux distro that I've tried), the screen refresh rate is stuck at 40HZ, even though the laptop supports 165HZ. In display settings and in xrandr output, 165HZ is shown as the selected rate. Though, I can clearly see the refresh rate is way lower as it is also shown by glxgears.

The problem is not present when I change the switchable graphics setting in BIOS to "dGPU only". With it selected, the display correctly sets and uses 165HZ. But when it's either set to "iGPU only" or "MSYHBRID", the same problem occurs.

I've tried:

- Setting the refresh rate to 40HZ and then back to 165HZ (No effect)
- Using a lower resolution with 60HZ selected (Still displays at 40HZ)
- Using the nouveau driver (Same behavior)
- Using the proprietary NVIDIA driver (Same behavior)
- Switching to Wayland (An additional option of selecting 60HZ is added to the settings, but it is also not effective in any way)
- Using various distros such as Fedora, Manjaro, etc. (Same behavior with each)

Xrandr Output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   2560x1440    165.00*+  40.00 +
   1920x1440     85.00    75.00    60.00  
   1856x1392     75.00    60.01  
   1792x1344     75.00    60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1600x1200     85.00    75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00  
   1680x1050     84.94    74.89    69.88    59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     85.00    74.76    70.00    59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     85.02    75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      85.00    60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864     100.00    85.06    85.00    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      85.00    75.05    60.04    85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1024x768i     86.96  
   960x720       85.00    75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       85.00    75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    85.14    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       85.02    74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       85.08    74.76    70.06    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       85.02    75.02    60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       85.09    60.00    85.01    72.81    75.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       85.04  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98    85.08  
   576x432      100.11    85.15    85.09    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   640x350       85.08  
   512x384       85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x384i      87.06  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       85.27    72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       85.18    72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   360x200       85.04  
   320x200       85.27  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   320x175       85.27  
DP-1-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

lspci | grep VGA Output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
```

glxgears Output:

```
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
268 frames in 5.0 seconds = 53.471 FPS
201 frames in 5.0 seconds = 40.000 FPS
201 frames in 5.0 seconds = 40.001 FPS
201 frames in 5.0 seconds = 40.000 FPS
201 frames in 5.0 seconds = 40.001 FPS
201 frames in 5.0 seconds = 40.001 FPS
```

Let me clarify that, in Windows with all 3 BIOS settings, the refresh rate works as expected and is 165HZ.
And I am also using the internal display of the laptop at all times.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Same here. I have RTX 3070 but others are same.

Answer (score 0):

same problem here, try modesetting for intel.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1192752)

Comment: Can you provide more details?  This answer would be improved if you could provide clear step-by-step instructions that can be easily replicated by the question's author and any other visitors who have this same question.